# Fully Homomorphic Encryption over the Integers - perform an operation on an encrypted data

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption, function-evaluation

In Fully Homomorphic Encryption scheme represented here [Fully Homomorphic Encryption over the Integers](http://eprint.iacr.org/2009/616)

In the Evaluate process (see section “3.1 The Construction” of the paper):
$$Evaluate(pk, C, c1, \dots , ct):$$

Now…

1. If I want to do some operations on an encrypted data, should I convert that operation to a binary circuit, then do the operation, and re-encrypt the final result?
2. If I have this simple binary circuit below, how could I evaluate the process?

   > [image: Simple binary circuit to compute]
3. What is the data that will be passed to the Input A and input B?
4. And how can I determine the number of addition and multiplication operations that will be used?

I did not understand how to do it from the Paper.

Comment: Hi, this link is dead

Answer (score 5):

It's actually straight-forward; we'll assume that all the inputs are either encrypted versions of 0, or encrypted version of 1; then:

- We can replace an AND gate with just an FHE multiplication of the two inputs:

  $$AND(x,y) = x*y$$

  Where $*$ is our Homeomorpic multiplcation operation.  This obviously evaluates to an encrypted 1 if both of the inputs are encryped 1's; and an encrypted 0 if either of the inputs are encryped 0's
- To replace an exclusive or gate, we encrypt the constants 1 and -1, and then compute:

  $$XOR(x,y) = x*(1 + (-1 * y)) + y*(1 + (-1 * x))$$

  Where *+* is our homeomorphic addition operation, and 1 and -1 stand for our encrypted constants.
- To replace an or gate, we take our encrypted 1 and -1 constants, and compute:

  $$OR(x,y) = 1 + -1 * (-1 + x) * (-1 + y)$$
- To replace a NOT gate (that doesn't appear in your circuit, but does come up in others), we compute:

  $$NOT(x) = 1 + -1 * x$$

It is easy to see that, in all cases, if the inputs are restricted to encrypted 0 and encrypted 1, the result is either an encrypted 0 or an encrypted 1 (and which will be the logical result of the operation).  Obviously, things can be simplified somewhat if our FHE operation includes a subtraction operation.

As for the number of operations used, we just translate each gate and count them up.  On the other hand, this construction is really a proof that just addition and multiplication suffice to be complete operations (that is, given just those two operations, we can compute anything); when you look at operation count, it turns out to be quite inefficient.

Comment: The fact that addition and multiplication can't turn 0s into a 1 shows that they are _not_ complete operations. (However, addition and multiplication _and_ $-1$ suffice to be complete operations.)

Comment: @RickyDemer: with FHE, it is assumed that we can take any value, and generate an encrypted form of it with the public key.  I assumed that as part of my demonstration; if those aren't available, the problem could include a fixed encryption of -1.

Comment: $XOR(x,y)$ and $OR(x,y)$ can be simplified to $\:x+y+((-2)*x*y)$ $\hspace{2.15 in}$ and $\:x+y+((-1)*x*y)\:$ respectively. $\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: cool!